# I have no idea what I am supposed to do

Tags: jquery, flash, popup, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been trying to get a SWF file to work in FancyBox. FancyBox itself works properly, the only trouble I'm having is when I use SWF files.

This is the HTML part:

```
<div id="box-6" class="box"> <a class="various" href="content/test.swf">swf</a>
    <img id="image-6" src="/image_28.png"/>
    <span class="caption scale-caption">
    <h3> test <br><em><font size="1"> test </em></font></h3>
        <p> test </p>
  </span>
```

And this is the JS part, at the very top of my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});


$('#single_3').fancybox({
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'outside'
        }
    }
});
});
```

When I click on the image nothing happens though.

I also tried to put it like this, still nothing happens:

```
<a id="single_3" <a class="various" href="content/test.swf" title=" test ">swf</a>
<img id="image-6" src="/image_28.png"/>
<span class="caption scale-caption">
<h3> test <br><em><font size="1"> test </em></font></h3>
    <p> test </p>
```

I have no idea what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind fancybox to a single selector, either your ID or your class (if planning to bind fancybox to several elements then use classes instead) so

having this html :

```
<a title="Lorem ipsum" class="various" href="content/test.swf">Open SWF</a>
```

... make sure that the path to the *swf* file is correct

Then, use a single script and set all your API options in there :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        // all your API options here, whatever they are
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            }
        },
        type: "swf" // you need to say is a swf content
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that we added the option `type: "swf"` so fancybox will know the `type` of content it needs to handle.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BRXxE/)** for a working sample.